# Picking Geolocation every after certain time interval

Tags: dart, flutter

Am new to Dart-flutter, and I need to write an app that can pick user location in the background after say an hour.
I have tried to work things around the geolocation plugin and Timer class, which worked fine but only picks the location once.
I need to know if there is a service workaround or the best way to go about this.

thank you

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
   static const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);

   @override
   State createState() => new HomePageState();

   HomePage(){
     startTimeout();
   }

   startTimeout()async {
    final GeolocationResult result = await 
      Geolocation.isLocationOperational();
      if(result.isSuccessful) {
      return new Timer(timeout, handleTimeout);
    } 
     else {
       debugPrint(result.error.toString());
       GeolocationResult res = await 
       Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(const LocationPermission(
       android: LocationPermissionAndroid.fine,
       ios: LocationPermissionIOS.always,
       ));

        if(res.isSuccessful) {
           new Timer.periodic(timeout,(Timer t)=> handleTimeout);
        } else {
         debugPrint(res.error.toString());
        }
     }
  }

 void handleTimeout(){
      debugPrint("Print after 10 seconds");
        Geolocation.currentLocation(accuracy: 
          LocationAccuracy.best).listen((result) {
        if(result.isSuccessful) {
            var posts = new postservice.Post();
            var userid=100;



posts.sendLocation(result.location.latitude,result.location.longitude,userid);

         }
    });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you tried. You can use `Timer.periodic` and `Stream.interval`

Comment: i have edited, that is the class i wrote

Comment: If `result.isSuccessful` is `true` `return new Timer(timeout, handleTimeout);` is executed, this probably should be `Timer.periodic()` like a few lines below.

Comment: hey,nothing is happening now it is performing evrything in starttimeout () but not the periodic call to handletimeout()